# Google Analytics in PHP Header?

Tags: php, html, google-analytics

I am new to PHP but learning slowly. Problem I have is including Google Analytics in my header.

I have created a separate php file for the code but my issue is including this in the PHP HEADER file below:

I believe that the issue is the @$content[1] .='  tag - but I need to include this as this is how my site is built.

How would I put the Google Analytics code before the  tag without confusing the php code in the file.

Thanks in advance. (I would ask my developer but I want to learn myself).

HEADER FILE PHP CODE BELOW:

```
<?php

@$content[1] .='
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
<title>Title</title> 
<link id="www-core-css" rel="stylesheet" href="template/css/core.css"> 
<link id="www-core-css" rel="stylesheet" href="template/css/style.css">
</script></head> 
<body>
<div id="page" class=""> </div>
<div id="masthead-container"> 
    <div id="masthead" class="">
        <a href="index.php"> 
            <button id="logo" class="master-sprite" title="Online ePub Builder"></button> 
        </a> 

        <div align="right"> 
            <script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-6078741672481332";
/* UK 1 */
google_ad_slot = "5428463210";
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 90;
//-->
 </script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
        </div>';

    if(is_login()) {
$content[1] .='<div id="masthead-utility"> 
            Hello, <a href="user.php">'.$_SESSION['uidrealname'].'</a> 
            &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
            <a href="logout.php">Sign Out</a> 
        </div>';
    } else {
$content[1] .='<div id="masthead-utility"> 
            <a href="login.php">Create Account</a>
            &nbsp; &nbsp; or &nbsp; &nbsp; 
            <a href="login.php">Sign In</a> 
        </div>';
    }


$content[1] .=' <div id="masthead-nav-user"> 
            <a href="help.php">Help</a>
                <a href="guide.php">FREE Guide</a> 
        </div> 
        <div id="masthead-nav-main"> 
            <a href="new.php">New Book</a> 
            '.(is_login() ? '<a href="books.php?    u='.$_SESSION['uid'].'">My Books</a>' : '').' 
        </div> 
        <div id="masthead-end"></div> 
    </div> 
</div> 
<div id="baseDiv"> 
<div id="homepage-main-content" class="">';
?>
```

Comment: You can simply insert it in there between the </script> and </head> tags, although if your site has multiple 'headers' you may need to include this on all of them. It's also generally better to include it at the end of your html code rather than in the <head> section. I would check with your developer before you touch anything though, even if you do want to learn...

Comment: thanks for answer - although problem is multiple headers - and same issue if i stick it in the footer

Comment: I think you need to add a bit more information, as it isn't clear what the problem is. Can you paste the PHP code that you are trying to use when you say the code gets "confused"? It should just be a case of adding the google analytics code to the head tag. If this isn't working, could you also paste the relevant part of the rendered HTML (i.e. grab it from your browser's view source)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the file content:

```
$trackingCode = file_get_contents('yourFile');
```

Then just add this into your string just before the end of your head like so:

```
<link id="www-core-css" rel="stylesheet" href="template/css/style.css">
</script>
'.$trackingCode.'
</head>
```

Comment: cool - where would I place the first bit - $trackingCode = file_get_contents('yourFile');  - thanks

Comment: Before your concatenation start `@$content[1] .='`

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean that you want the Google analytics JavaScript in the html `<head>` tag - the PHP header is generally understood to be the HTTP headers sent to the client's browser.

If this is the case, just put the google analytics script somewhere before the closing head tag `</head>`.

P.s. you currently have a random `</script>` tag with no opening tag just before your closing `</head>` - delete it!

Comment: Sorry - Please ignore that extra script tag - but the issue is that it gets confused when i post analytics script directly in to the php loop - thanks

Answer (score 0):

you just need to put Google analytic script between `<head>`    `</head>` tags like,

`<head>`

`<script type="text/javascript">`

//past your Google analytic script here

`</script>`

`</head>`

Answer (score 0):

Tip i would put the code in footer and not the header so you get the true page load time